# Convergence of average probability in Markov chain

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory, markov-chains

Let $P$ be a [stochastic matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix), and let $v_0$ be a probability vector for the initial distribution. So $v_k=P^kv_0$ is the probability vector for the distribution at time $k$, and $v_{ki}$ is the probability of being in the $i$th state at time $k$.

Is it true that for any fixed $i$, the sequence $$\left(\frac{\sum_{j=1}^kv_{ji}}{k}\right)_{k=1}^\infty$$
converges? Is there a result that guarantees this? I've looked at the [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), but it doesn't seem to imply anything about this sequence.

Also, if we let $T_k(i,j)$ be the random variable giving the number of transitions from $i$ to $j$ between times $1$ and $k$, then does $T_k(i,j)/k$ converge as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consequence / special case of the ergodic theorem for Markov chains.  If $N_k(i)$ is the random variable giving the number of visits to $i$ between times $1$ and $k$, the ergodic theorem asserts that $N_k(i)/k$ converges almost surely.  Since this ratio is bounded by $1$, the dominated convergence theorem says that its expectation also converges, and that is precisely the quantity you desire.  (Let $\chi_j(i) = 1_{\{X_i = j\}}$ be the indicator of the event that we are in state $i$ at time $j$, and note that $N_k(i) = \sum_{j=1}^k \chi_j(i)$; then use linearity of expectation.)

You can see Durrett's *Essentials of Stochastic Processes*, Theorem 1.9, for an elementary proof, or his *Probability: Theory and Examples*, Theorem 6.6.1, for a more measure-theoretic argument.  These are under the assumption that the chain is irreducible, but you can reduce to that case by writing $v_0$ as a convex combination of vectors supported on irreducible sets, with a little extra work if there are transient states.

Comment: Thanks! And if we let $T_k(i,j)$ be the random variable giving the number of transitions from $i$ to $j$ between times $1$ and $k$, then does $T_k(i,j)/k$ converge as well? I imagine it should be true too, but it doesn't seem to follow directly from the ergodic theorem.

Comment: @pi66: Yes, that is also true.  You can easily adapt the proof of the statement I gave - the key is that by the strong Markov property, the times between successive transitions from $i$ to $j$ are iid, so the law of large numbers applies.  Or, you can look at a modified chain where between each pair of vertices, you insert a new vertex, and then count the number of visits to this intermediate vertex.